# Is (x <= y) or ! (x > y) more efficient?

Tags: c++, performance

I want to know which one of these snippets is faster.

I usually use this expression:

```
if(x <= y)
    break;
```

But is there an advantage to using this?

```
if(!(x > y))
    break;
```

---

Here is my reasoning. I think that first statement is actually this:

```
if(x == y)
    break;
if(x < y)
    break;
```

But I think the second statement is only this:

```
if(!(x > y))
     break;
```

This leads me to believe that the second statement is faster. Is this right?

Comment: Look at the assembly output from an optimized build.

Comment: If `<=` is overloaded, it's almost always implemented as `!(x > y)`.

Comment: Okay, then why is there `jle` and `jng`? Or are they the same instruction?

Comment: @BlueIce In x86 assembler they are synonyms for the same op-code (binary 0x7E)

Comment: Ok. So there is no difference, then.

Comment: For integers, they are the same, and the compiler knows it. For floating point, they can give a different answer (NaN), so what matters most is which answer you actually want (if you don't care, tell it to the compiler, and again the compiler will know).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compiled using `gcc -O3 -march=native -m64 -fomit-frame-pointer -S`:

```
int f(int x, int y) {
    if (x <= y) return 1;
    return 0;
}

f:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpl    %edx, %ecx
    setle   %al
    ret
```

and

```
int f(int x, int y) {
    if (!(x > y)) return 1;
    return 0;
}

f:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpl    %edx, %ecx
    setle   %al
    ret
```

That is, for integers they are exactly equal - in fact the compiler optimized **the second example to the first, because it was faster, not slower**.

Comment: using `(a==b || a<b)` with at least `-O1` gives the same result

Answer (score 4):

It is very unlikely that the compiler will generate something different from the other. 
Nearly all modern processors have a `greater or equal` or `less or equal` comparison/branch operation, so there should be no reason to make a more complex comparison.

The statement

```
 if(x == y) 
      if (x < y) 
         break;
```

doesn't make any sense. Either `x == y` is true, in which case `x < y` is not true. Or `x == y` is false, and you don't enter the second if at all.

Obviously, if `x` and `y` are a class, then the `operator<=` may be written as:

```
operator<=(const A& x, const A& y)
{
    if (x == y) return true;
    return x < y; 
}
```

But that would be rather daft, since it can just as well be written as :

```
operator<=(const A& x, const A& y)
{
    return !(x > y); 
}
```

Comment: I can be wrong but it makes more sense to discuss the differences between a deque and a vector than try to pick one from this 2 options, also generally speaking C++ leaves a lot of freedom to the C++ compiler, this question is just feticism for the code. I share the vision where data structures and algorithms are all you need to code and focus on to create a program, everything else is just pointless, your compiler can do a lot better than you.

Comment: Better than me, or better than the original poster? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming x & y are built in types,

> Here is my reasoning. I think that first statement is actually this:

```
if(x == y)
    if(x < y)
        break;
```

This is not right. The CPU can do `<=` operations. Don't over-optimize ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can expect any sufficiently advanced compiler to automatically optimize these equivalent statements to the one fastest on the target architecture, so in practice they will behave the same.

But when these snippets would be interpreted literally, on the x86 architecture the first would be a single operation, because the x86 CPU instruction set has instructions for both jump-when-less and for jump-when-less-or-equal.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of int (or short or long long or whatever), just use `x <= y`, and the compiler should optimize it. For example on x86-64:

```
    cmpq %rax, %rcx
    jg false
#This is code to execute if (x <= y).
# Code
# .......
false:
    #This is code to execute once the
    # if statement is done or the condition
    # resulted in a falsy value.
```

If you have an if-else statement, there are two jump instructions: the first is if the condition yields a falsy value, and the second is at the end of the code block for when the condition yields a truthy value (so it can skip over the code used for the else block).

Notice that I used a jg (jump if greater than) instruction. The x86 and x86-64 both have a jnle (jump if not less than or equal) instruction as well, but it does the same thing (after all, if x is not less than or equal to y, then logically x must be greater than y), but from the standpoint of working in ASM, it makes more sense to invert the condition. Had the condition not been inverted, you would have jumped forward to execute the code for the if statement, and jumped backward to resume the main flow of the program. Why do in two jumps what you can do with one?

BTW, I'm no ASM guru. However, if you work with it a little, it can help you to avoid asking questions like these because the compiler should optimize your `(x <= y)` condition to `!(x > y)` code anyway as I've shown. There is no need to try second guessing your compiler. Focus on the normal optimizations you can make to help the compiler optimize your code, such as eliminating conditions that don't need to execute in the first place, not the small stuff that it already knows how to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons why you should use `<=`

1. The CPU can do `<=` operations for primitives.
2. If the classes have an overloaded operator `<=` it's safe to assume it's optimized to do just that better than `if(!(x > y))` or at least equal to it. So if it exists, use it. Someone made an effort to implement it for a reason.